# Is there a better approach in SQL to group actions by day/week/month/year/alltime?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm thinking my way to do that is a little archaic, not optimized... i don't need super detailed statistics, lets say i want the number of clicks on a link on a blog post per (actual) day/week/month/year nothing more, don't want the hour of click, just a number for each corresponding times (day/month/year).

I've created this table :

```
CREATE TABLE `clicks` (
  `file_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `day` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `week` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `month` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `year` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `all` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)
)
```

And each time there's a click, i update every column of a row by +1.

```
UPDATE clicks SET day = day+1, week = week+1 [..] WHERE file_id = $id
```

And at every end of day/week/month/year there's a cronjob who will reset the corresponding column for every file. For each day end it will be :

```
UPDATE clicks SET day = 0 [No WHERE Clause]
```

And when there's new click on a file tomorrow, it'll increment the day column again.

I have a small VPS server, small storage space, small RAM etc.. i just need how many times a file has been clicked this day only (not yesterday), this week (not the week before) etc.. and i'm trying to not have big & slow queries by having a line for each click and having millions of them.

Is my way of doing seems ok, or is there a better approach for what i want ?

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @GeorgRichter Yeah, i was not sure, i choose the easy way, i'll edit that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table just storing the clicks, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE clicks (
    file_id INT NOT NULL,
    filename VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    click_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Then you just need to use the group by, to extract the clicks. For Example:

```
-- group clicks by day
SELECT DATE(click_time) AS day, COUNT(*) AS clicks
FROM clicks
GROUP BY day;

-- group clicks by week
SELECT YEARWEEK(click_time) AS week, COUNT(*) AS clicks
FROM clicks
GROUP BY week;
```

This is quite more efficient and requires less storage

Comment: as he wants only 1 day you can add a where clause, so no group is needed

Comment: Certainly more efficient, i've already thought of something like that, but how it is using less storage than my solution ? I increment 4 columns numbers, with yours there'll be a row for each click, if there's a million clicks, then a million rows. Since i'm not interested in keeping history of each click time, your solution don't work with me. But thanks a lot for your help/input !

Comment: Yes it will result in more storage being used compared to the original approach. The main advantage of the this one is that it allows for more efficient querying of the data

Answer (score 0):

Build and maintain a "Summary table" by date.  Only summarize by `DAY`, then sum up the counts to get "by week", etc.  That also lets you get the tallies for arbitrary ranges of days.

More on [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)